# How to rotate part of a mesh?

Tags: mesh

I've noticed that sometimes, when I select the face of an object, let say a cube, then i press rotate only the selected face will rotate and not the other faces, there will not be affected by the rotation.
But sometimes when I select a face and rotate it, the other faces will stay attached and will also move and will be stretched.

Same thing for edges.
Here other faces are stretched, however sometimes only the selected edge will be moved away.

[image]

However I don't know why and how to switch between this two "modes".

Comment: If you want other parts of the mesh to move in keeping with the transformation of individual elements (ie faces, edges, etc...) use proportional editing (keyboard shortcut O). You can change the area of influence by scrolling the mouse wheel (represented by the white circle on screen), and change the edit type by selecting a mode from the rightmost box of the 4 dropboxes at the top-center of the 3d Viewport (Proportional Editing Falloff options).

Comment: Sounds like the difference between proportional editing, and ordinary editing.. 'O' is the shortcut.. button just to the right of the Snap section in the header.

Comment: Thank you Christopher and Robin for your answers. Even i've i'm still a beginer, i'm not 100% sure it is what i'm talking about, because sometime even if i don't use shorcut "O" other parts move with selected face or edge. Is it maybe something aboyt "y" shorcut ?? Thanks a lot for your time guys :)